# How to Enable/Disable button on TinyMCE textbox onkeyup or onkeydown

Tags: c#, asp.net

on a ascx page I have a tinymce editor and a button

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="100%" ></asp:TextBox>
<test:tinymceextender runat="server" ID="TinyMceExtender" TargetControlID="txtName" Theme="Full"> </test:tinymceextender>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" Enabled="false" runat="server" />
```

I want to check if, textbox is null, then btnsave should be disable, if textbox is not null its should be enable, for the first time its working(because i am checking it on Page_Load), as I am entering some text and deleting that text using backspace btn is in enable mode only. I tried it to do with onKeyUp, onKeyPress but its working working for TinyMCE

these 2 js I used but its not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    var my_editor = tinymce.get('<%=txtName.ClientID %>');
    if ($(my_editor.getBody()).text() == '') {
        $("#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else if ($(my_editor.getBody()).text() != '') {
        $("#<%=btnSave.ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

---

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
}
function ENABLE_BTN() {
    var EN = tinymce.get('<%=txtName.ClientID %>');
    if (EN == '') {
        document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

calling onkeydown="ENABLE_BTN() on txtName

on F12: my textbox code is looking something like this...

```
  <fieldset>

  <input id="BasePage_txtName" type="text" style="width: 100%; display: none;"  name="BasePage$txtName" aria-hidden="true">
  <span id="BasePage_txtName_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin" role="application" aria-labelledby="BasePage_txtName_voice">
  <span id="BasePage_txtName_voice" class="mceVoiceLabel" style="display:none;">Rich Text Area</span>
  <table id="BasePage_txtName_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">
  <tbody>
  <tr class="mceFirst" role="presentation">
  <tr class="mceLast">
 </tbody>
   </table>
  </span>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `keyup` event to check if the contents are empty like this. Edit: updated to use TinyMCE's weird eventhandler methods.

```
$(function () {

  tinyMCE.init({
    // adapt accordingly
    mode : "exact",
    theme : "simple",
    elements : "txtName", 
    setup : function(ed) {
               ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
                     bindKeyUp(ed);
           });}
             });
});

function bindKeyUp(ed) {
 if (tinyMCE.activeEditor) {
    ed.onKeyUp.add(function() { 
      $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', !(textBoxEmpty()));
    });
 }
}

function textBoxEmpty() {
 var contentLength = tinyMCE.get('#txtName').getContent();
    if (contentLength.length) {
      return true;
    }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: not working, debugger is not going on Keyup function when debugging through F12

Comment: I am using tinyMCE.init in a separate js file with extender I can't add it on page level

Comment: I don't see why it would'n work on init if it's done on another page.

Comment: if tinymce is on same page then its working fine, but in my condition, tinymce is on other solution...

Comment: I don't get it. On your particular project, can you control the tinyMCE.init() ?

Comment: thank you its working now... plz check my ans also, I modified a bit in ur's and now its working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

 tinyMCE.init({
// adapt accordingly
mode : "exact",
theme : "simple",
elements : "txtName", 
setup : function(ed) {
           ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
                 bindKeyUp(ed);
       });}
         });
```

});

```
function bindKeyUp(ed) {
    if (tinyMCE.activeEditor) {
        ed.onKeyUp.add(function () {
            var contentLength = removeHTMLTags(tinyMCE.get('<%=txtName.ClientID %>').getContent());
            if (contentLength.trim().length) {
                document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID %>').disabled = true;

            }

        });
    }
}
```