# Trouble getting a reference to TinyMCE editor instance

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm using the jQuery plugin for TinyMCE and have had a hard time trying to figure out how to reference an instance after it's been initialized.  My goal is to remove a menu item.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var el = $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        script_url : '../lib/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        plugins: "paste,visualchars,customspecialchars,customvariables,customfootnotes",
        theme : "advanced", 
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bullist,|,customspecialchars,customvariables,customfootnotes,|,undo,redo,|,cut,copy,paste",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"
    });

    console.log(tinyMCE);  //undefined since I'm using jquery plugin
    console.log($(el).tinymce());
    $('input[name^="footnote"]').keyup(function () {
        console.log(editor);
    });
});
```

That's my init code (note the custom plugins).  I can't figure out how to call [tinymce.ui.DropMenu.removeAll()](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.ui.DropMenu.removeAll) on my jquery tinymce instance

Comment: Perhaps this can [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682484/how-to-enable-disable-button-on-tinymce-textbox-onkeyup-or-onkeydown/9683139#9683139)

Comment: @CodrinEugeniu - That post isn't using the jquery plugin.  In the jquery plugin you don't have a tinyMCE variable defined.

Comment: i strongly recommend not to use the tinymce jquery build, it is slow

Comment: $(el).tinymce() seems to work after the TinyMCE is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the editor instance:

```
tinymce.get($(el).attr('id') || 'content');
```

Comment: That would work if `tinymce` was defined.  It's not using the jQuery plugin.

Comment: then don't use the tinymce build (as i suggested) - it's the faster choice. the jquery build is pretty slow when it comes to keyboard interaction

Comment: @Sentinel: this answer did solve the askers question (and btw. is using jQuery)